Meaning of gold border around Steam achievement
I was browsing my Steam library, and I noticed that one of my games had a glowing gold border around the achievement picture. Originally, I thought that it was to tell me I had a new achievement, so I tried clicking on it, but it just opened the full achievement list, which is what you see above. I tried clicking on it again, but no change.
What does this gold border mean?

If the achievement has below 10.0% global completion, it will glow gold.
Looks like this was added sometime around September 2019. Example source: https://www.pcgamesn.com/steam/gold-achievements
I didn't find an authoritative source for this, but 10.0% as the cutoff matches the screenshot and also my own games.

Are there other colours for rarer achievements (less than 5%, 1%, etc?)

@Daemons 2.9% displays the same as just under 10%. I don't believe I have anything below 1%, but I doubt it has a unique effect.

It means it's a rare achievement (<10% attainment rate)
Source
